# Adding a hyperlink to a CRM 2011 note

Tags: hyperlink, dynamics-crm-2011

I am looking into how i can create a hyperlink to a webpage on the body of a note in CRM 2011 via C#. I have tried adding the code to the text eg. `<a href=\"" + destination + "\">SharePoint</ID></a>` but this simply types it in. Is there any way that this can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, inspecting the Note's text field in the browser reveals that it's a TextArea DOM element.  Since these aren't capable of displaying anything but plain text, I'd suggest you're probably out of luck.  Sorry about that :)

You could edit the form to add a new field of type URL, if that's helpful?

Comment: No worries, i kinda had that feeling myself about it, but was asking just out of hope! Thanks anyway